# How to change a base64 value which is in string to byte?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I have a variable which is in bytes for example:

```
k=b'gAAAAABfGakqAaKNJwYTmdsERYzv9_o9rAOpwPjRSGYxBIRKHYfUgh7CtMrZpJMrxkH8bc0dami_D2tOO8EOHNZkZiHWZUTvmw=='
```

<class 'bytes'>
now if I convert this to string using str(k)
value of k:

```
b'gAAAAABfGakqAaKNJwYTmdsERYzv9_o9rAOpwPjRSGYxBIRKHYfUgh7CtMrZpJMrxkH8bc0dami_D2tOO8EOHNZkZiHWZUTvmw=='
```

<class 'str'>

Now if i need the original byte version of the variable how do i convert it? Because if I use bytes(k,'encoding') i get the bytes version of the new string and the value changes to

```
b"b'gAAAAABfGawb3lL2uGxUSlKw4ujOts_7TMGtXBlbDddhBZ_0VgHylkpbrKtFqtU0CDz4gaenzDIuNTd3zM9ydksOnd6nQaz9Sw=='"
```

<class 'bytes'>
Can someone tell me how can I get back the original data type from the string value of the variable?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of casting the bytes as a string, decode it in utf-8:

```
In [9]: k=b'gAAAAABfGakqAaKNJwYTmdsERYzv9_o9rAOpwPjRSGYxBIRKHYfUgh7CtMrZpJMrxkH8bc0dami_D2tOO8EOHNZkZiHWZUTvmw=='                          

In [10]: s = k.decode('utf-8')                                                                                                             

In [11]: s                                                                                                                                 
Out[11]: 'gAAAAABfGakqAaKNJwYTmdsERYzv9_o9rAOpwPjRSGYxBIRKHYfUgh7CtMrZpJMrxkH8bc0dami_D2tOO8EOHNZkZiHWZUTvmw=='

In [12]: bytes(s, 'utf-8')                                                                                                                 
Out[12]: b'gAAAAABfGakqAaKNJwYTmdsERYzv9_o9rAOpwPjRSGYxBIRKHYfUgh7CtMrZpJMrxkH8bc0dami_D2tOO8EOHNZkZiHWZUTvmw=='
```

Comment: base64 is ascii based. utf-8 will work, but I think "ascii" makes more sense.

Comment: @tdelaney ascii is a subset of utf-8. Both will work here.

Comment: ...which I made clear in my comment. Why not CP1252? Many encodings are supersets of ASCII, but none of the superset characters are legal in base64. Any encoding other than ASCII is arbitrary.

Comment: Hey thanks  a lot ! but If my variable is already in string how do I convert it then?